# cakephp "Config doesnt exist" in session

Tags: cakephp

I am using the Cake's inbuilt auth module . Everything is working fine on my production environment . However on my local environment , I am not able to login . 
I traced out that the problem is because the sessions seems to get reset on every redirect . As a result of which cake is not able to find one of it's array ( Config) in the session variable . 
I have tried setting the security level to medium/low  , but to no use .

Please help.

This is what my session object looks like :

```
SessionComponent Object
(
    [__active] => 1
    [__started] => 1
    [__bare] => 0
    [valid] => 1
    [error] => Array
        (
            [2] => Config doesn't exist

            [1] => Session is valid
        )

    [_userAgent] => 
    [path] => /
    [lastError] => 1
    [security] => low
    [time] => 1278498179
    [sessionTime] => 1282098179

    [watchKeys] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => 
    [_log] => 
    [host] => localhost
    [enabled] => 1
    [cookieLifeTime] => 788940000
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok . I solved it . It had to do with the permissions of my folders on the local environment . 
I hope this post helps somebody .

Answer (score 0):

This could also be because your website was loaded from some other server or email link or something.

> ```
> One common problem is if the link you are following is from a
> different HOST the php session has a session.referer_check which is
> set to the HTTPS_HOST for security high and to HTTP_HOST for security
> medium, it is not set for security low. This causes the session to be
> reset if the referer is not the host that is being called. In other
> words if you followed a link from an email or some other server that
> points to your app. This also presents when going back and forth
> between the root app/domain and a root/sub app/domain because the the
> HTTP_HOST can changes (if one site is using blah.blah.com and the
> other is using localhost or ip address)
> Often we all have code to read in a cookie to remember a user that has
> previously logged in. This often just masks and hides the problem. So
> we don't notice most of the time when the session was dropped until we
> start to rely on a saved value that we thought we saved to the session
> or when the user cookie expires and we are redirected to the login
> page. So these often times appear very random when in reality they are
> not. If your having what appears to be intermediate session lost, its
> very likely its occurring more than you think. Some debugging is
> needed.
> ```
>
> The only difference I can determine between security medium and
>   security low is timeout duration and setting the php
>   session.referer_check.

Source: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Auth-losting-authentication-with-no-reason-td1331403.html

Hope this helps someone in need.